# Easy rules is stateless?

Tags: easy-rules

Does easy-rules support a stateful rule-engine like Drools?

I would like to re-execute other rules if the fact is updated by one of the rule.

Please let me know if this is supported by easy-rules.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not stateful.

You could implement statefulness yourself by storing state in a `static` structure and run rules over the state by treating it as *facts* whenever state changes.